# Pinnacle Python API not working

Tags: python

I've been trying to get live odds data from Pinnacle. However I am struggling a bit with some of the syntax and haven't found a solution after searching through google, so I am hoping someone here can help me.

```
from pinnacle.apiclient import APIClient
api = APIClient("XXX", 'XXX')
FS = api.market_data.get_line(sport_id=29,league_id=2036,event_id =? ,period_number =?,bet_type ='moneyline')
print(FS)
```

My first two issues is that I have no idea what the event_id is and period number is. I can however type random numbers into them and then I get the following error message:

> {'TIMESTAMP': '2018-03-13 15:22:54.339630', 'code':
>   'INVALID_REQUEST_DATA', 'message': 'The Team is required. The valid
>   team types are: Team1,Team2,Draw', 'Latency': 0.083467}

So I am also unsure where I should enter `Team1`, `Team2` in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check the [documentation](https://pinnacleapi.github.io/linesapi#tag/Line). From there:

> periodNumber
>
> This represents the period of the match. For example, for soccer we have 0 (Game), 1 (1st Half) & 2 (2nd Half)

The event ID is just a unique identification representing an event in a league (say, a match between Barcelona and Rial Madrid). You can use [the fixtures API](https://pinnacleapi.github.io/#tag/Fixtures) to get these numbers.

The `team` is only required for specific bet types (which you probably guessed as well):

> Chosen team type. This is needed only for SPREAD, MONEYLINE and TEAM_TOTAL_POINTS bet types

Basically to identify which team the bet is referring to (1,2 or draw).

Comment: Thanks a lot - made it work. If you have time for one more question, could you tell me how I only get one value, e.g. the odds or the time the game starts?

Comment: I'm not sure - post another question, with the output you get and what you want, and link it here - I'll have a look.